# Complex removal MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete the numbers except the biggest one with the day and name

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_1m` (
  `name` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test_1m` (`name`, `rate`, `dt`) VALUES
('kurkuma', '0.00002150', '2018-04-06 12:04:01'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002151', '2018-04-06 12:04:02'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002152', '2018-04-06 12:04:03'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002153', '2018-04-06 12:04:04'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002159', '2018-04-06 12:04:05'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002154', '2018-04-06 12:04:06'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002155', '2018-04-06 12:04:07'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002156', '2018-04-07 12:04:08'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002157', '2018-04-07 12:04:09'),
('pahlava', '0.0000001', '2018-04-06 12:04:02'),
('pahlava', '0.0000002', '2018-04-07 12:04:02');
```

must be

```
('kurkuma', '0.00002159', '2018-04-06 12:04:05'),
('kurkuma', '0.00002157', '2018-04-07 12:04:09'),
('pahlava', '0.0000001', '2018-04-06 12:04:02'),
('pahlava', '0.0000002', '2018-04-07 12:04:02');
```

Maybe something like this. just does not work =)

```
DELETE * FROM `test_1m`
WHERE NOT (
    SELECT max(rate)
    FROM `test_1m`
    GROUP BY `name`, DATE(`dt`)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you have to express filtering on the same table using a `join`:

```
delete t
    from test_1m t join
         (select name, date(dt) as dt, max(rate) as rate
          from test_1m
          group by name, date(dt)
         ) tt
         on tt.name = t.dt and tt.dt = t.date and
            t.rate < tt.rate;
```

If this is removing a significant number of records (like more than a few percent of the table), it might be faster to truncate and re-insert:

```
create temporary table tokeep as
    select t.*
    from test_1m t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from test_1m t2
                      where t2.name = t.name and
                            date(t2.dt) = date(t.dt) and
                            t2.rate > t.rate
                      );

truncate table test_1m;

insert into test_1m
    select * from tokeep;
```

Of course test the code and backup the table before trying this.

Comment: Uh, I understood how it works =).
You have a small error `tt.dt = date(t.dt)`.
And this request is very long for 3 million records.

Comment: How about it: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tokeep
  select name, max(rate) rate, dt 
  from test_1m
  group by name, date(dt);

truncate table test_1m;

insert into test_1m
  select * from tokeep;`

Comment: @YarNik . . . The `GROUP BY` might be faster.